# Information received from an invalid ip address

Tags: php, magento, opayo

When trying to place an order on a Magento site I have enabled Sagepay on, I receive the following error at checkout:

> Information received from an invalid ip address

I have already tried adding the IP address of the server, the IP address when I ping the domain, as well as trying the solution offered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17648542/why-am-i-getting-the-error-4020-information-received-from-an-invalid-ip-addre), yet still receive the error. Is there anything else I can try?

Comment: checked this link too : https://ebizmarts.com/forums/topics/view/5 ?

Comment: @SunilVerma - The link in step one of that thread goes to a 404...

Comment: As a note to anyone else, the Sage Pay Simulator mentioned in @SunilVerma link is no longer in use - SagePay confirmed this when I phoned support.

Answer (score 0):

Turned out this was an error on my part - the "Vendor" within the ebizmarts Magento module was incorrect...